# find a funciton $f(x,y,z)$ such that $grad f=F$, where $F$ is the given vector field

Tags: partial-derivative, vector-analysis, vector-fields, curl

So I have this vector field $$F=\langle 2xe^{x^2y}, e^{x^2}, 1\rangle$$

I am asked to find a function such that $grad f=F$

However, when I check its curl, I got $$\begin{bmatrix}
\vec i & \vec j & \vec k\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\\
2xe^{x^2y} & e^{x^2} & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

I end up with $(2xe^{x^2}-2x^{3}e^{x^2y})\vec k \ne 0$

Since this vector is not conservative, I conclude that there's no such function $f$ where $grad f=F$.

But the question sounds very firm, did I miss something?

Comment: If it were me, I would accept "no such $f$ exists because curl$F$ is nonzero".  Show your work and you should be fine.  It is a poorly worded question, though (that, or the instructor/book did not check their answer first!)

Comment: I checked multiple times and made sure I didn't make any typo. So yeah, this is probably a poorly worded question as you suggested.